# Rails, Logout on Back Button in Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

Quick question here.

I'm creating a 3-step form for a user - all AJAX (and using Devise). The user is created on the first step, and updated on the second two steps.

Now, the issue is that if a user hits the back button in their browser to go back to the first step, the Devise automatically changes the form action to `update`. But, the my `update` action renders partials that should only be rendered in steps 2 and 3 via Ajax.

How can I make it so that the user is logged out when hitting the back button so that the first form is always a `new_user` form?

Comment: Do you need to create the object on the first step?  Have you tried using the wicked [gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) for creating your form?

Comment: well, the reason I chose Devise is so that the object is indeed created on the first step (and I can update it later).

Comment: wicked is a gem for creating multi-step forms, so your object won't be created until the last step, which will allow you to use the back button in the way you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to disable back button in browser at all.

You can use a modal to implement the three steps. If you are using Ajax, use it at full.

By this, there is no "back" button on the browser. But you can still have "back" button on your modal window, in this case the back option is totally in your control.

**Add**

For usability you should allow users to update their info at any time, instead of forcing them to complete all right after signed up.

I don't know what your next two steps are. But you can

1. Setup the `update` method to render the next two steps if an user has not finished them, or render other info if finished.
2. Show a notice if an user is signed in but has not finished the two steps.

By these you should be able to ensure whatever the user do on their browser, he can see what he need to do next. These should be applicable to either Ajax or no Ajax.

Comment: I like this - but if I'm doing this and using Devise for authentication, the user is still logged-in right? So, they could hit the refresh button, and I'd have the same problem.